# Linux: System-Wide High Contrast Theme?

Tags: windows, gui, linux-distribution

Is there a Linux desktop environment/other kind of solution that offers a high-contrast theme such as the one in Windows that is system-wide? Preferably that works with softwares as well.

Something as closet to/even better than Window's high contrast themes, which are:

- Very quick to configure
- Very simple to switch on/off
- Work with various softwares

I want to migrate to Linux from Windows but the lack of a high contrast, system-wide, easy-to-configure solution, at least from my research so far, is for now a deal-breaker to me - at least for using a desktop envrionment.